# Projective line equivalence classes

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Define a relation on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ by letting $(x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2)$ is there exists a nonzero real number $\lambda$ such that $(x_1,y_1) = (\lambda x_2,\lambda y_2)$. Prove that $\sim$ defines an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. What are the corresponding equivalence classes?

**Attempt:**

Clearly $(x,x) \in R$ for all $x$ and if $(x_1,y_1) \in R$, then $(y_1,x_1) \in R$. Now if $(x_1,y_1) \in R$, and $(y_1,z_1) \in R$, then we have $\lambda_1 x_1 = \lambda_1 y_1$ and $\lambda_2 y_1 = \lambda_2 z_1$ which implies $x_1 = z_1$.

How do I find the equivalence classes?

Comment: Hint: Anything is equivalent to exactly one of $(x,1)$  or $(1,0)$. By the way, for transitivity multiply the first equation by $\lambda_2$ and the second by $\lambda_1$.

Comment: You need to show   
---(1)---   $(x,y) \sim (x,y)$   
---(2)---   $(x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2) \implies (x_2, y2) \sim (x_1, y_1)$   
---(3)---   $(x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2)\; \text{and}\; (x_2,y_2) \sim (x_3,y_3) \implies (x_1, y1) \sim (x_3, y_3)$